# JDK path configuration option is not available while configuring from jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins ver. 2.96. I navigated to Jenkins>Manage Jenkins>Configure System. I am not able to see the configuration of JDK and Maven.

Comment: please post what error you are getting. what you have tried so far

Comment: Hi Sasikumar, 

I am not able to see JDK and Maven configuration in Jenkins UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Configure Java, Maven, Git

1. Go to Jenkins url
2. Go to Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration
3. **To Add JDK**, Click `Add JDK` button under JDK then uncheck Install automatically(if you have already installed JDK in your machine) then specify the Name(Just for reference inside jenkins) and JDK home.
4. **To Add Maven**, Navigate to Maven tab and Select Maven Installation then Click `Add Maven` button then specify Name and maven home.

I believe this will help you setup jdk and maven in your jenkins